# In bar chartjs report zero values are skipped so bars are invalid

Tags: chart.js

I have stacked bar (Chart.js Version: 2.7.2 )  with 2 values of vote type(correct / not correct).
It works ok except cases when there are some data on correct votes and no data on non correct votes. And vice versa
To salve this problem I added some check on server and for nonexisting values I add rows in 0 value in count field, so set of data looks like

Please pay attention that for voteItemUsersResultsNoneCorrect array row with id":4,"vote_name":"Which fictional city is the home of Batman ?"},
field count has 0 value. Looking at resulting bar chart I see that 0 value was skipped and value FROM NEXT row was used to build the chart, so all next bars
are invalid.

```
{"error_code":0,"message":"",
    "voteItemUsersResultsCorrect":{"0":
        {"count":9,"id":12,"vote_name":"According to the old proverb, to which European capital city do all roads lead ?"},"1":
        {"count":6,"id":13,"vote_name":"On which mountain did Moses receive the Ten Commandments ?"},"2":
        {"count":10,"id":9,"vote_name":"Traditionally, how many Wonders of the World are there ?"},"3":
        {"count":6,"id":10,"vote_name":"What is the name of the fairy in Peter Pan ?"},"4":
        {"count":12,"id":8,"vote_name":"Which crime-fighting cartoon dog has the initals \u201cS.D.\u201d on his collar ?"},"5":
        {"count":16,"id":4,"vote_name":"Which fictional city is the home of Batman ?"},"6":
        {"count":5,"id":14,"vote_name":"Which is the tallest mammal?"},"7":
        {"count":8,"id":11,"vote_name":"Which planet is the closest to Earth ?"},"10":
        {"count":0,"id":2,"vote_name":"Who Framed Roger Rabbit ?"},"8":
        {"count":8,"id":15,"vote_name":"Who directed the movie Jaws?"},"9":
        {"count":8,"id":5,"vote_name":"Who was known as the Maid of Orleans ?"}},

    "voteItemUsersResultsNoneCorrect":{"0":
        {"count":22,"id":12,"vote_name":"According to the old proverb, to which European capital city do all roads lead ?"},"1":
        {"count":25,"id":13,"vote_name":"On which mountain did Moses receive the Ten Commandments ?"},"2":
        {"count":21,"id":9,"vote_name":"Traditionally, how many Wonders of the World are there ?"},"3":
        {"count":25,"id":10,"vote_name":"What is the name of the fairy in Peter Pan ?"},"4":
        {"count":19,"id":8,"vote_name":"Which crime-fighting cartoon dog has the initals \u201cS.D.\u201d on his collar ?"},"10":
        {"count":0,"id":4,"vote_name":"Which fictional city is the home of Batman ?"},"5":
        {"count":26,"id":14,"vote_name":"Which is the tallest mammal?"},"6":
        {"count":23,"id":11,"vote_name":"Which planet is the closest to Earth ?"},"8":
        {"count":27,"id":2,"vote_name":"Who Framed Roger Rabbit ?"},"7":
        {"count":23,"id":15,"vote_name":"Who directed the movie Jaws?"},"9":
        {"count":23,"id":5,"vote_name":"Who was known as the Maid of Orleans ?"}
    }
}
```

I show fully retrieving of data and setting bar options,
At first I have to set values for 3 arrays monthsXCoordItems, voteNamelabels, voteValuesCorrect and created bar chart on them .

```
$.ajax({
    url: href,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataArray,
}).done(function (response) {
    if (response.error_code == 0) {

        this.this_voteItemUsersResultsCorrect = response.voteItemUsersResultsCorrect
        this.this_voteItemUsersResultsNoneCorrect = response.voteItemUsersResultsNoneCorrect

        for (var key_index in response.voteItemUsersResultsCorrect) {
            if (response.voteItemUsersResultsCorrect.hasOwnProperty(key_index)) {
                var dataRow= response.voteItemUsersResultsCorrect[key_index];
                monthsXCoordItems.push(dataRow.vote_name);
                voteNamelabels.push(dataRow.vote_name);
                voteValuesCorrect.push(dataRow.count);
            }
        }

        for (var key_index in response.voteItemUsersResultsNoneCorrect) {
            if (response.voteItemUsersResultsNoneCorrect.hasOwnProperty(key_index)) {
                var dataRow= response.voteItemUsersResultsNoneCorrect[key_index];
                voteValuesNoneCorrect.push(dataRow.count);
            }
        }

        var barCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasVoteNames");
        $("#div_canvasVoteNames").css("display","block")

        var barCanvasContext = barCanvas.getContext('2d');

        var numberWithCommas = function (x) {
            return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        };
        var self = this;
        if (window.chartObject != undefined) { // clear existing instance
            window.chartObject.destroy();
        }
        window.chartObject = new Chart(barCanvasContext, {  
            type: 'bar', // http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html
            data: {
                labels: monthsXCoordItems,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Correct Votes',
                    data: voteValuesCorrect,
                }, {
                    label: 'Incorrect Votes',
                    data: voteValuesNoneCorrect,
                }
            ]
        },

        options: { // options of Report By Vote Names
            animation: {
                duration: 10,
            },

            scales: { // options for x and y scales
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,    
                    gridLines: {
                        display: true,
                        // offsetGridLines: true,
                    },
                    // barThickness: 70,

                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true, 
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function (value) { 
                            if (Math.floor(value) === value) {
                                return value;
                            }
                        }, 
                    },
                }],
            }, // scales: { // options for x and y scales
            legend: {display: true}
        }, // options: { // options of Report By Vote Names


        plugins: [{
            beforeInit: function (chart) {
                chart.data.labels.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
                    var a = [];
                    a.push(value.slice(0, this_column_width));
                    var i = 1;
                    while (value.length > (i * this_column_width)) {
                        a.push(value.slice(i * this_column_width, (i + 1) * this_column_width));
                        i++;
                    }
                    array[index] = a;
                })
            }
        }]

    }); 

    barCanvas.onclick = function (e) { 
        var slice = window.chartObject.getElementAtEvent(e);

        if (!slice.length) return; // return if not clicked on slice
        var label = slice[0]._model.label;
        if (label.length > 1) { // that is an array - we need to convert it to string
            var label_text = ''
            for (var key in label) {
                if (label.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    label_text = label_text + label[key]
                }
            }
            label = label_text
        }
        self.this_voteItemUsersResultsCorrect.forEach(function (data) {
            if (label == data.vote_name) {
                backendReports.showVoteNamesReportDetailsByVoteId(data.id, data.vote_name)
                return;
            }
        });
    } // barCanvas.onclick = function(e) {
}

if (response.error_code > 0) {
    alertMsg(response.message, 'Reports error!', 'OK', 'fa fa-file-chart-pie')
}
});
```

Are some ideas how to fix this error ?

MODIFIED BLOCK # 2 :
I uploaded that chart online: please open
http://votes.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/admin/report_votes_by_vote_names
there is creditials provided and by default page with all data will be opened, but value for 
"Which fictional city is the home of Batman " ivalid as it has 0 value for noncorrect stack : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me76Y.jpg

You can see valid results with 0 value if select the only vote from voyes filter selection :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uPKp.jpg
?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is `count: 13, id: 4` and `count: 22, id: 2` ...

which means, your script is confusing Batman with Roger Rabbit.

there might be further values wrong; it only gets the most obvious with `0` values.

better merge the arrays on the server-side, to have them readily consumable for the chart; this would permit easier index assignment - and it would also speed up the run-time of the JS. less complexity is commonly easier the handle than useless complexity (as it is with client-side merging of the arrays).

Comment: 1) From first look I do not see your point : i made a lot of calculations on server(php) and 
got  3 simple arrays   monthsXCoordItems, voteNamelabels, voteValuesCorrect with proper structure and it seems that the problem 
is that in implementation of the bar setting x points there is a condition like 
if (! empty(XValue)) {  // somehow 0 value is true here - why?
   Lets get x Value from next point asnd that raise the invalid results
}

Comment: 2) Could you please explain How that could be "your script is confusing Batman with Roger Rabbit." ?
There are different id, count, name fields and 3 different arrays monthsXCoordItems, 
voteNamelabels, voteValuesCorrect : you can see their value by live url.